# Instead of Empty space need special character as hyphen

Tags: mysql

By this query, I am displaying empty if we have any null value in the table, but I need a special character like hyphen

```
  SELECT COALESCE(prereq, '') FROM test
```

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(prereq, '-') FROM test` ?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried that It won't work

Comment: Define "don't work."  What doesn't work?

Comment: I said it won't work. not don't work...:)

Comment: what error you are getting while using SELECT COALESCE(prereq, '-') FROM test? As i think it is correct and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ifnull function for get string or special character like:

`SELECT IFNULL(prereq, 'String') AS prereq FROM test`